# Get the current location using python

Tags: python, gps, location

Hi I am trying to get the location of my computer using python.
I looked at the web and nothing.
Is it even possible in python?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this question could be reworded?  Are you asking "Is there a GPS library in python?" If so...[Is there any GPS library for use in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346453/is-there-any-gps-library-for-use-in-python)