# Python - Fetching data from two serial ports in realtime

Tags: python, parsing, math, gps, real-time

**My project**  is a directional antenna which is mounted on a self-stabilizing base. The language I wish to use is python, but changing this to a more suited language, is a possibility, if needed.

#### Problem 1:

How would you go about taking in serial data in real-time**[1]**, and then parse the data in python?

#### Problem 2:

How can I then send the output of the program to servos, which are mounted on the base? (feedback system).

**[1]**(Fastest possible time for data transfer, processing and then output)

Comment: What hardware are you using for servos and how are they interfaced to the computer?

Comment: As much as I love Python, I'm not sure I'd consider it suitable for realtime programming.

Comment: @Payne I am going to be using a PIC mircocontroller and connecting it via a FTDI serial contevertor which plugs into a USB making a "Virtual Com port"

Comment: @Nathan I do agree, but I am most familiar with python than other programming languages. If you could help me embed my code (above) into a suitable language. It would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What firmware/system will you be using on the PIC microcontroller to drive the servos?  That will dictate how you send data from the host computer to move the servos.

Comment: @Payne 9600 BAUD UART -PIC16F628a

Comment: You'll need to get software for your PIC to control the servos.  And that software will dictate how things work from your host PC.

Comment: @Payne Thanks...back to the parsing annd receiving how can I recive the data and use in my equation above? I have had a look at pyserial before but can't get my head around it quite..

Comment: Unfortunately, pyserial is about as simple/basic as it gets for reading the serial port in Python.  I'd recommend starting with the code examples, and writing a simple starter program that reads GPS data lines and just prints them out.  Once you get that working, you can add your parsing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pyserial` module to read serial port data with Python.  See:  http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html

Here's a short usage example from the docs:

```
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS1', 19200, timeout=1)
>>> x = ser.read()          # read one byte
>>> s = ser.read(10)        # read up to ten bytes (timeout)
>>> line = ser.readline()   # read a '\n' terminated line
>>> ser.close()
```

Next, you'll need to parse the GPS data.  Most devices support "[NMEA 0183](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183)" format, and here's another SO question with information about parsing that with Python:  [Parsing GPS receiver output via regex in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311763/parsing-gps-receiver-output-via-regex-in-python)

Finally, outputting data for servo control will depend entirely on whatever hardware you are using for the servo interface.